# Unable to access my static IP address in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, static-ip-address

I am not able to access the services through my external static IP address ON Googgle Cloud Platform.
The same services are accessible through localhost:port# but not through externalIP:port#.
I am using all the default Firewall settings where the IP filters are all 0.0.0.0/0 and the Protocol/Port is set to tcp:8090
8090 is the port where my service is running.

Anyone know what I need to set or change?

Comment: your company might have block that IP. First try to ping IP from local pc ..

Comment: I am accessing the GCP service machine from my home machine..there is no firewall on my side. Am able to ping the static external IP address from my windows 10 terminal.  I am also able to access the service from the terminal connected to the GCP VM instance using localhost:port#. I am trying to access the same service from my browser - replacing the localhost with the static external IP address....but am not able to,. My GCP firewall filter uses the default setting as in 0.0.0.0/0 for the service I m trying to access. Am not sure what setting I need to change.

Answer (score 1):

The link from the Google Cloud Panel points to https://ip_address, if you have no SSL certificate you won't be able to connect.
Insted you have to write yourself the http protocol on the browser